# Factory with Composite or Abstract Factory

Tags: java

I have following class hierarchy:

```html
public interface RateSheetProductExtractor
{
  List<ProductData> extract(SGQuotingData quotingData);
}


@Service
@Scope("requestjob")
public class ProductExtractorFactory
{
  @Autowired
  private OptionalRatingProductExtractorFactory optionalRatingProductExtractorFactory;
  @Autowired
  private QuotePlanProductExtractorFactory quotePlanProductExtractorFactory;
  @Autowired
  private AlternateProductExtractorFactory alternateProductExtractorFactory;

  public RateSheetProductExtractor getProductExtractor(
    TablePlanType tablePlanType,
    TableRatingType ratingType)
  {
    switch (tablePlanType)
    {
      case QUOTED:
        return quotePlanProductExtractorFactory.getInstance(ratingType);
      case OPTIONAL:
        return optionalRatingProductExtractorFactory.getInstance(ratingType);
      case ALTERNATE:
        return alternateProductExtractorFactory.getInstance(ratingType);
      default:
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(tablePlanType + " is unsupported yet.");
    }
  }
}

@Service
@Scope("requestjob")
public class OptionalRatingProductExtractorFactory
{
  @Autowired
  private AcaProductExtractor acaProductExtractor;
  @Autowired
  private AgeRatedAsCompositeProductExtractor ageRatedAsCompositeProductExtractor;

  public RateSheetProductExtractor getInstance(TableRatingType ratingType)
  {
    switch (ratingType)
    {
      case AGE:
        return ageRatedAsCompositeProductExtractor;
      case COMPOSITE:
        return acaProductExtractor;
      default:
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(
          "Product extractor isn't defined for optional plan type and rating type " + ratingType);

    }
  }
}


@Service
@Scope("requestjob")
public class QuotePlanProductExtractorFactory
{
  @Autowired
  private GfProductExtractor gfExtractor;
  @Autowired
  private AgeRatedProductExtractor ageRatedProductExtractor;
  @Autowired
  private MedicalProductExtractor medicalProductExtractor;

  public RateSheetProductExtractor getInstance(TableRatingType ratingType)
  {
    switch (ratingType)
    {
      case AGE:
        return ageRatedProductExtractor;
      case COMPOSITE_AGE:
        return gfExtractor;
      case COMPOSITE:
        return medicalProductExtractor;
      default:
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(
          ratingType + " is unsupported for QuotePlan product extractor factory.");
    }
  }
}


@Service
@Scope("requestjob")
public class AlternateProductExtractorFactory
{
  @Autowired
  private AlternateAgeRatedProductExtractor ageRatedProductExtractor;

  public RateSheetProductExtractor getInstance(TableRatingType ratingType)
  {
    if (ratingType == AGE)
    {
      return ageRatedProductExtractor;
    }
    throw new IllegalArgumentException(
      ratingType + " is unsupported for QuotePlan product extractor factory.");
  }
}
```

would it be correct to call ProductExtractorFactory as AbstractProductExtractorFactory(based on the appropriate pattern)? or it's more like a simple factory of factories?

Sorry for huge listing...:)

Comment: Considering that `ProductExtractorFactory` is never extended anywhere, I would say no, it should not be named `AbstractProductExtractorFactory`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont think so.

1) `ProductExtractorFactory` is a concrete class and in Java and even in AbstractFactory pattern the class that starts with Abstract is/should be an abstract class.

2) In Abstract factory you should have a concrete subtype of `RateSheetProductExtractor` for each factory but in your code example I dont see them.

3) You example is more like a Factory along with Composite pattern.

**Refactoring to use composite:**

Define common factory interface:

```
public interface RateSheetProductExtractorFactory{

    public RateSheetProductExtractor getProductExtractor(TablePlanType tablePlanType, TableRatingType ratingType);
}
```

Define composite class:

```
public class CompositeRateSheetProductExtractorFactory implements RateSheetProductExtractorFactory{
    private Map<String, RateSheetProductExtractorFactory> factoryMap = null;

    public void setFactoryMap(Map<String, RateSheetProductExtractorFactory> factoryMap){
        this.factoryMap = factoryMap;
    }

    @Override
    public RateSheetProductExtractor getProductExtractor(TablePlanType tablePlanType, TableRatingType ratingType){
        RateSheetProductExtractorFactory factory = factoryMap.get( tablePlanType + "-" + ratingType );

        if (factory == null) throw new IllegalArgumentException( tablePlanType + "-" + ratingType + " is unsupported yet.");

        return factory.getProductExtractor(tablePlanType, ratingType);
    }        
}
```

Implements each extractor and their individual factories:

```
public class AcaProductExtractorFactory implements RateSheetProductExtractorFactory{

    @Override
    public RateSheetProductExtractor getProductExtractor(TablePlanType tablePlanType, TableRatingType ratingType){
        return new AcaProductExtractor();
    }
}

public class AcaProductExtractor implements RateSheetProductExtractor{

    @Override
    public List<ProductData> extract(SGQuotingData quotingData) {
        return null;
    }        
}



public class AgeRatedAsCompositeProductExtractorFactory implements RateSheetProductExtractorFactory{

    @Override
    public RateSheetProductExtractor getProductExtractor(TablePlanType tablePlanType, TableRatingType ratingType){
        return new AgeRatedAsCompositeProductExtractor();
    }
}

public class AgeRatedAsCompositeProductExtractor implements RateSheetProductExtractor{

    @Override
    public List<ProductData> extract(SGQuotingData quotingData) {
        return null;
    }        
}



public class MedicalProductExtractorFactory implements RateSheetProductExtractorFactory{

    @Override
    public RateSheetProductExtractor getProductExtractor(TablePlanType tablePlanType, TableRatingType ratingType){
        return new MedicalProductExtractor();
    }
}

public class MedicalProductExtractor implements RateSheetProductExtractor{
    @Override
    public List<ProductData> extract(SGQuotingData quotingData) {
        return null;
    }       
}
```

Spring XML:

```
<bean id="ageRatedAsCompositeProductExtractorFactory" class="AgeRatedAsCompositeProductExtractorFactory"/>
<bean id="medicalProductExtractorFactory" class="MedicalProductExtractorFactory"/>
<bean id="acaProductExtractorFactory" class="AcaProductExtractorFactory"/>

<bean id="extractorFactory" class="CompositeRateSheetProductExtractorFactory">
    <property name="factoryMap">
        <map>
            <entry key="QUOTED-AGE" value-ref="ageRatedAsCompositeProductExtractorFactory" />
            <entry key="QUOTED-COMPOSITE" value-ref="medicalProductExtractorFactory" />
            <entry key="ALTERNATE-AGE" value-ref="ageRatedAsCompositeProductExtractorFactory" />
            <entry key="OPTIONAL-COMPOSITE" value-ref="acaProductExtractorFactory" />
        </map>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Comment: There is also a possible Delegation pattern involved in here where ProductExtractorFactory delegates creation to 3 other factories.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Actually, I wanted to extract common interface for all factories and implement it but currently, I'm not quite clear what preferences it might give me...

Comment: Actually I understood your suggestion little bit different - I created interface `ProductExtractorFactory` with 2 methods - `  RateSheetProductExtractor getInstance(TableRatingType ratingType);` and `boolean isApplicable(TablePlanType planType);` so each particular factory overrides method `isApplicable` to identify for which type it needs to be invoked. But I suppose it's almost the same as you suggested.

Comment: but based on this post https://dzone.com/articles/design-patterns-abstract-factory - I'm still not quite sure why I could call `ProductExtractorFactory ` as `AbstractFactory`...

Comment: They are. In my example the rules of which Factory to select are defined in the map. In your case they are defined in each concrete factory implementation.

Answer (score 0):

My two cents is to keep the name as it is. I am not sure about your workplace but at my previous organizations we used to keep the class name as Abstract*SomeClass* if it was an abstract class and a concrete class has to implement its methods. If you check the Java Collections API also, all classes starting with *Abstract* has more to do with this concept rather than the design pattern.